# Client-Server app architecture with custom communication protocol

Tags: c++, client-server, qt

I am working on Qt/QML/C++ based Client-Server software system with custom protocol. Now, in both projects inside QtCreator I have same **header** and **implementation** files inside both projects.

What is the best way to eliminate duplicated files, or, if I put **custom communication protocol** inside library, is this the right path, or are there maybe some other/better solutions?

Comment: put common code in a library. That's what libraries are there for.

Comment: Is the custom communications protocol a requirement or are you just writing a custom protocol to solve a problem?    You might want to look at existing communication mechanisms to make sure you aren't re-inventing the wheel:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/118945/best-c-c-network-library

Comment: @BenCottrell thank you for your link, I've been already using `Qt`, what I want now to establish simple `TCP/UDP` socket communication between my applications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like @bbjbaand [said](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/314134/client-server-app-architecture-with-custom-communication-protocol#comment663825_314134), I did put common code inside dedicated library, works perfectly!